# PDF rotation solution for react native android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, pdf

I have a conversations application that I'm developing which can support messaging, sending images, videos, and specifically for this issue PDF files as well, I really want to make it possible so the PDF file would be able to rotate between portrait mode and horizontal mode, without making the user rotate their device, so the user experience when viewing PDFs would be compromised.

I tried to search online but the only results I managed to find were 3+ years old npm package that are not maintained or even not documented sufficiently, including pdf-lib and some of it's forks and 2 other packages that I can find their names in my download history.